# How to get rid of backslash and unicode from json using python

Tags: python, json, apache-nifi

I am new to python, in fact this is the first time in my life I am writing python scripts, writing a code to create Json stings out of a template using NiFi.
I have a file, first line of that file is a template, second line onwards are parameters to replace in the template and form json strings

eg file.txt

1. template
2. value1
3. value2
4. value3

I have to create 3 JSON strings out of it.

an example :

```json
{
  "order": {
    "createCSI": {
      "operation": "add",
      "specification": {
        "name": "TEST",
        "version": "SNAPSHOT"
      },
      "parameters": "${parameters}"
    }
  },
  "relatedPartyMap": {
    "user": {
      "name": "batch"
    },
    "customer": {
      "name": "${customerName}"
    },
    "referenceId": {
      "name": "CSI"
    },
    "service": {
      "name": "CSI"
    },
    "operation": {
      "name": "CreateCSI"
    }
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "parameters": {
    "service": {
      "serviceCharacteristicsMap": {
        "customer": {
          "description": "test",
          "address": "Av. Joan Carles I, 64 08908 L'Hospitalet de Llobregat Barcelona",
          "name": "Anglo-Mining-2",
          "contact": "Contact"
        },
        "delayTolerance": false,
        "uplinkThroughputPerNetworkSlice": {
          "maximumUplinkThroughput": 9753023.28,
          "guaranteedUplinkThroughput": 25802621.2
        },
        "downlinkThroughputPerNetworkSlice": {
          "maximumDownlinkThroughput": 33310543.92,
          "guaranteedDownlinkThroughput": 51787067.62474576
        },
        "uplinkThroughputPerUE": {
          "maximumUplinkThroughput": 9753023.28,
          "guaranteedUplinkThroughput": 25802621.2
        },
        "downlinkThroughputPerUE": {
          "maximumDownlinkThroughput": 9753023.28,
          "guaranteedDownlinkThroughput": 51787067.62474576
        },
        "sNSSAIList": [
          {
            "sst": 1,
            "sd": "31"
          }
        ],
        "pLMNIdList": [
          {
            "mnc": "162",
            "mcc": "113"
          }
        ],
        "maximumNumberOfPDUSessions": 100,
        "isolationLevel": "LOGICAL-ISOLATION",
        "maximumNumberOfUEs": 500,
        "areaOfService": [
          [
            [
              [
                104.34722353935285,
                25.773165978336877,
                -23530344.27915588
              ],
              [
                124.35910593569582,
                -21.39165650037988,
                -31712857.508380473
              ],
              [
                -73.44012657013947,
                -59.06718512641518,
                78549684.45440823
              ],
              [
                113.5971561119145,
                -1.8824766907913641,
                -83065409.80793653
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "customerName": "batman"
}
```

I am using a split text processor to from a flowfile with header (template) and a value.
Initially I wrote a script that would load the data of the template and values , then would replace the required part with with the dict formed from value. This was working without any unicodes or backslashes in the output.

code used:

```py
import json
import sys
import traceback
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback
from org.python.core.util import StringUtil
    class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
        try:
            
            input_text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            #log.info("input_text >"+input_text)
            incoming_flow = input_text.split('\n')
            template = incoming_flow[0]
            values = incoming_flow[1]
            #log.info("template >"+template)
            #log.info("values >"+values)
            template_obj = json.loads(template)
            parameter_obj = json.loads(values)
            if "parameters" in parameter_obj:
                parameters = parameter_obj['parameters']
                
                if "customerName" in parameter_obj:
                    customerName = parameter_obj['customerName']

                if "orderItemMap" in template_obj:
                    if "createCSI" in template_obj['orderItemMap']:
                        template_obj['orderItemMap']['createCSI']['parameters'] = parameters
                if "relatedPartyMap" in template_obj:
                    if "customer" in template_obj['relatedPartyMap']:
                        template_obj['relatedPartyMap']['customer']['name'] = customerName
                
                #log.info("parameters >"+str(json.dumps(parameters)))
                #log.info("customerName >"+str(json.dumps(customerName)))
                #log.info("parameter_obj >"+str(json.dumps(parameter_obj)))
                #log.info("input_obj >"+str(json.dumps(input_obj)))
            elif "imsi" in parameter_obj:
                  imsi = parameter_obj['imsi']
                  if "msisdn" in parameter_obj:
                      msisdn = parameter_obj['msisdn']
                      numList = [ {"imsi": imsi, "msisdn": msisdn  } ]  
                      #log.info("numList >>> " + str(json.dumps(numList)))
                      if "orderItemMap" in template_obj:
                          if "createMobileSubs" in template_obj['orderItemMap']:
                             if "numberList" in template_obj['orderItemMap']['createMobileSubs']['parameters']:
                                template_obj['orderItemMap']['createMobileSubs']['parameters']['numberList'] = numList
                    
            else:
                log.info("The Template does not match")
            
            output_text = str(json.dumps(template_obj))
            outputStream.write(bytearray(output_text.encode('utf-8')))

        except:
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
            raise


flowFile = session.get()
if flowFile != None:
    try:
        flowFile = session.write(flowFile, PyStreamCallback())
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    except ValueError as ve :
        attrMap = {}
        attrMap["Script.Exception"] = ve
        session.putAttribute(flowFile,'error_val',str(attrMap))
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)        
    except Exception as e:
        attrMap = {}
        attrMap["Script.Exception"] = e
        session.putAttribute(flowFile,'error_val',str(attrMap))
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
```

but it turns out there could be many number of files and the templates would be different from what was given to me.

hence I moved to using Template()  from string import Template

```py
import json
import sys
import traceback
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback
from org.python.core.util import StringUtil
from string import Template

    class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        
    def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
        try:
            
            input_text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            #log.info("input_text >"+input_text)
            incoming_flow = input_text.split('\n')
            template = incoming_flow[0].strip()
            values = incoming_flow[1].strip()
            #log.info("template >"+template)
            #log.info("values >"+values)
            template_obj = json.loads(template)
            parameter_obj = json.loads(values)
            
            tpl = Template(template)
            #log.info("parameter_obj >"+str(parameter_obj))
            #log.info("template >"+str(tpl))
            json_string = tpl.substitute(parameter_obj)
            #log.info("json_string >"+str(json.dumps(json_string)))
            
            output_text = json.dumps(json_string,ensure_ascii=False)
            outputStream.write(bytearray(output_text.encode('utf-8')))

        except:
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
            raise


flowFile = session.get()
if flowFile != None:
    try:
        flowFile = session.write(flowFile, PyStreamCallback())
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    except ValueError as ve :
        attrMap = {}
        attrMap["Script.Exception"] = ve
        session.putAttribute(flowFile,'error_val',str(attrMap))
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)        
    except Exception as e:
        attrMap = {}
        attrMap["Script.Exception"] = e
        session.putAttribute(flowFile,'error_val',str(attrMap))
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
```

this seams to be working , but i am getting a lot of unicode and backslashes. this was not happening while i was replacing using dict made from json.loads

formed json

```
{ \"order\": { \"createCSI\": { \"operation\": \"add\", \"specification\": { \"name\": \"TEST\", \"version\": \"SNAPSHOT\" }, \"parameters\": \"{u'service': {u'serviceCharacteristicsMap': {u'uplinkThroughputPerNetworkSlice': {u'maximumUplinkThroughput': 9753023.28, u'guaranteedUplinkThroughput': 25802621.2}, u'delayTolerance': False, u'maximumNumberOfUEs': 500, u'downlinkThroughputPerUE': {u'maximumDownlinkThroughput': 9753023.28, u'guaranteedDownlinkThroughput': 51787067.62474576}, u'downlinkThroughputPerNetworkSlice': {u'maximumDownlinkThroughput': 33310543.92, u'guaranteedDownlinkThroughput': 51787067.62474576}, u'areaOfService': [[[ [-73.44012657013947, -59.06718512641518, 78549684.45440823], [113.5971561119145, -1.8824766907913641, -83065409.80793653]]]], u'uplinkThroughputPerUE': {u'maximumUplinkThroughput': 9753023.28, u'guaranteedUplinkThroughput': 25802621.2}, u'sNSSAIList': [{u'sd': u'31', u'sst': 1}], u'isolationLevel': u'LOGICAL-ISOLATION', u'pLMNIdList': [{u'mnc': u'162', u'mcc': u'113'}], u'maximumNumberOfPDUSessions': 100, u'customer': {u'address': u\"Av. Joan Carles I, 64 08908 L'Hospitalet de Llobregat Barcelona\", u'description': u'test', u'contact': u'Contact', u'name': u'Anglo-Mining-2'}}}}\" } }, \"relatedPartyMap\": { \"user\": { \"name\": \"batch\" }, \"customer\": { \"name\": \"batman\" }, \"referenceId\": { \"name\": \"CSI\" }, \"service\": { \"name\": \"CSI\" }, \"operation\": { \"name\": \"CreateCSI\" } } }
```

please advise how to get rid of these backslashes and unicodes.
I created a processor with just json.loads to act as validator , that seams be in success, but the json in the flowfiles still have these

**UPDATE**

when i directly use json_string to the outputStream, it generates a string without any backslashes. To Validate the Json, I have created another processor.

```py
import json
import sys
import traceback
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback
from org.python.core.util import StringUtil


class TransformCallback(StreamCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
        try:
            
            input_text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            order_obj = json.loads(input_text)            
            output_text = json.dumps(order_obj)
            outputStream.write(bytearray(output_text.encode('utf-8')))

        except:
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
            raise


flowFile = session.get()
if flowFile != None:
    try:
        flowFile = session.write(flowFile, TransformCallback())
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    except ValueError as ve :
        attrMap = {}
        attrMap["Script.Exception"] = ve
        session.putAttribute(flowFile,'error_val',str(attrMap))
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)        
    except Exception as e:
        attrMap = {}
        attrMap["Script.Exception"] = e
        session.putAllAttribute(flowFile,str(attrMap))
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
```

this is giving me error

> {'Script.Exception': ValueError('Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 1503 (char 1502)',)}

But this script is working for some json strings not for some.

**working for this**:

> {"relatedPartyMap": {"referenceId": {"name": "Manager"}, "service": {"name": "Manager"}, "user": {"name": "batch"}, "operation": {"name": "createSubs"}, "customer": {"name": "ARCustomer"}}, "description": "createSubs", "orderItemMap": {"createSubs": {"specification": {"version": "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT", "name": "Manager"}, "operation": "createSubs", "parameters": {"snssai": "113ds3", "csiDN": "host,CSCustomer=Customer,eMBB=Service1", "mobileServices": ["Voice", "Voicemail", "Data"], "numberList": [{"imsi": "310310000000109", "msisdn": "443399900010"}], "customer": {"address": "768 5th Ave, New York, NY 10019", "description": "Augmented Reality & Co USA", "contact": "+1-000-754-3010", "name": "ARCustomer1234"}}}}, "category": "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"}

**Not working for**

> { "orderItemMap": { "createCSI": { "operation": "add", "specification": { "name": "TEST", "version": "SNAPSHOT" }, "parameters": "{u'service': {u'serviceCharacteristicsMap': {u'uplinkThroughputPerNetworkSlice': {u'maximumUplinkThroughput': 9753023.28, u'guaranteedUplinkThroughput': 25802621.2}, u'delayTolerance': False, u'maximumNumberOfUEs': 500, u'downlinkThroughputPerUE': {u'maximumDownlinkThroughput': 9753023.28, u'guaranteedDownlinkThroughput': 51787067.62474576}, u'downlinkThroughputPerNetworkSlice': {u'maximumDownlinkThroughput': 33310543.92, u'guaranteedDownlinkThroughput': 51787067.62474576}, u'areaOfService': [[[[-73.44012657013947, -59.06718512641518, 78549684.45440823], [113.5971561119145, -1.8824766907913641, -83065409.80793653]]]], u'uplinkThroughputPerUE': {u'maximumUplinkThroughput': 9753023.28, u'guaranteedUplinkThroughput': 25802621.2}, u'sNSSAIList': [{u'sd': u'31', u'sst': 1}], u'isolationLevel': u'LOGICAL-ISOLATION', u'pLMNIdList': [{u'mnc': u'162', u'mcc': u'113'}], u'maximumNumberOfPDUSessions': 100, u'customer': {u'address': u"Av. Joan Carles I, 64 08908 L'Hospitalet de Llobregat Barcelona", u'description': u'test', u'contact': u'Contact', u'name': u'Anglo-Mining-2'}}}}" } }, "relatedPartyMap": { "user": { "name": "batch" }, "customer": { "name": "batman" }, "referenceId": { "name": "CSI" }, "service": { "name": "CSI" }, "operation": { "name": "CreateCSI" } } }

suspect if it has got to do with address value

> "address": "Av. Joan Carles I, 64 08908 L'Hospitalet de Llobregat Barcelona"

The first code did not have any such issues

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: @daggett, I have updated with the code

Comment: Don’t `json.dump` what is already a string…!?

Comment: that removed the backslashes, but I am getting error_val {'Script.Exception': ValueError('Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 1503 (char 1502)',)}

Comment: Instead of guessing, make the input shorter, and figure out which part breaks it.

Comment: Please note that `u'mcc'` is not valid JSON (`“mcc"` is). You may want to clarify which example is in which format, and then also add other formats which are successfully generated from it.

Comment: it is the address part that is breaking 
"address": "Av. Joan Carles I, 64 08908 L'Hospitalet de Llobregat Barcelona"

it has a single quote between L and Hospitalet. When the single quote is not present, it is working.
Ran it through a json parser to check it

Comment: I was not able to come up with a solution when there is a single quote, the Json via template substitution was not validated. I used a series of replace to eventually make Json. Thought not the correct solution, I removed the single quote from the parameter first, then used it as parameter.
L'Hospitalet would be L Hospitalet.

I also noticed that the  template substitution  was converting boolean values to literals starting with Caps, false was False , True was True. has to change that as well.

Comment: parameter_obj = json.loads(values.replace("'"," "))
tpl = Template(template)
json_string = tpl.safe_substitute(parameter_obj)
json_string = json_string.replace("u'", "'")
json_string = json_string.replace('u"', '"')
json_string = json_string.replace('"{', '{')
json_string = json_string.replace('}"', '}')
json_string = json_string.replace("'", "\"")
json_string = json_string.replace("False", "false")
json_string = json_string.replace("True", "true")
outputStream.write(bytearray(json_string.encode('utf-8')))

Comment: That is way too much manual futzing with strings. Your fundamental problem is that you're putting text into text, [which is always problematic](https://kunststube.net/escapism). At the very least you need to do it in the logically correct order: make your template `{"parameters": ${parameters}, ...}` (**no quotes** around `${parameters}`), then `json.dumps` the value for `${parameters}`, so that it's a valid JSON value, then _then_ you can put it into your JSON template and the whole thing will be valid.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like json_string is already valid JSON, no need to encode it again with `json.dumps`.

Change

```
output_text = json.dumps(json_string,ensure_ascii=False)
```

to

```
output_text = json_string
```

Comment: that removed the backslashes, but I am getting 
error_val
{'Script.Exception': ValueError('Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 1503 (char 1502)',)}

Comment: You may want to ask a separate question about the error. Also make the test input and output much shorter.

Comment: The error is related, json.dumps(json_string,ensure_ascii=false) though it was giving backslash, the validation script was successful for all json strings. Now it's failing for some and passing for others.